# Проблема экспорта в CSV

Tags: php, yii

Пытаюсь сделать экспорт отмеченных позиций *CGridView* в *CSV*.

Когда я передаю *id* отмеченных записей *CGridView* контроллеру методом `$_POST`, браузер, вместо того чтобы показать запрос на открытие либо сохранение файла, возвращает ошибку 500 (причем *FireBug* показывает необходимые данные).

Если же в запросе контроллера я вместо массива, передаваемого из представления пишу обычный статичный массив - все прекрасно работает.

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я допустил ошибку?

Кнопка, отсылающая id записей контроллеру:

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array(
    'type' => 'primary',
    'size'=>'mini',
    'buttons' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Export',
            'type' => 'success',
            'buttonType'=>'ajaxLink',
            'encodeLabel'=>true,
            'icon'=> 'th white',
            'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('/propertyPurchaseSale/ExportChecked'),
            'ajaxOptions'=>array(
            "type" => "post",
            "data" => "js:{ids:$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection('property-purchase-sale-grid')}",
            "update" => '#', 'success'=>"js:function(data) {window.location.assign('/propertyPurchaseSale/ExportChecked');}"),                                                
                                  array( //htmlOptions
                                        )                                    
                                    ),
                    array(
                        ...
                    ),
                    ),
                )); 
?>
```

Действие контроллера:

```
<?php
public function actionExportchecked() {
            header('Content-type: text/csv');
            header('Content-type: multipart/form-data');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Export_(' . date('H-i_d.m.Y') .').csv"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

            if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            {
                if(isset($_POST['ids']))
                {       
                    $idx = $_POST['ids'];
                    $count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM property')->queryScalar();
                    // $sql='SELECT * FROM property WHERE id  IN (981, 982, 985)';  --> when I use static values - all work
                    $sql="SELECT * FROM property WHERE id IN('".implode("', '",$idx)."')";  // --> when I use join or implode function - data exist in firebug, but page return error 500

                    $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
                        'totalItemCount'=>$count,
                        'sort'=>array(
                            'attributes'=>array(
                                 'fullname', 'address', 'phone', 'db_number', 'created_date'
                            ),
                        ),
                        'pagination'=>false,
                    ));
                                        fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
                                        if ($fp)
                                        {                        
                            echo    PropertyPurchaseSale::model()->getAttributeLabel("id").";".
                                        PropertyPurchaseSale::model()->getAttributeLabel("fullname").";".
                                    PropertyPurchaseSale::model()->getAttributeLabel("address").";".
                                    PropertyPurchaseSale::model()->getAttributeLabel("phone").";".
                                    PropertyPurchaseSale::model()->getAttributeLabel("db_number").";".
                                    PropertyPurchaseSale::model()->getAttributeLabel("created_date").
                                    " \r\n";                        
                            foreach ($dataProvider->getData() as $data) {
                                echo $data['id'] . '; ' . $data['fullname'] . '; ' . $data['address'] . '; ' . $data['phone'] . '; ' . $data['db_number'] . '; ' . $data['created_date'] . '; ' . "\r\n";
                            }
                }
                        exit;
                    }
                }
}    
?>
```

Comment: Сделай `var_dump($idx);exit;` ниже `$idx = $_POST['ids'];`, посмотри, что вернется.

Comment: возвращает 
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "1367"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "1366"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "1365"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "1364"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "1362"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "1363"
}

Comment: да и в FireBug я вижу что действие контроллера возвращает нужные данные - не получается получить файл

Comment: Я обычно пишу так: `$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); fwrite($fp, 'Hello World!'); fclose($fp);` Я думаю нельзя просто взять и вызвать echo.

Comment: дело в том, что если я в значение $idx подставляю статичный массив, например array(584, 654, 75) - то файл возвращается, я думал что дело в том что в массиве $_POST['ids'] передается строка, пробовал $h = array_map( 'intval', array_filter($_POST['ids'], 'is_numeric')); но все равно страница возвращает ошибку 500

Comment: кстати я пробовал fputcsv - ситуация не меняется

Comment: А если без кавычек попробовать? `IN(".implode(", ",$idx).")` И у тебя логи настроены в конфиге? Что в лог application пишется?

Comment: Пробовал и с кавычками и без, в application.log ничего нет, в config\main.php 'levels' => 'trace, info, error, warning, vardump',
В логах веб-сервера тоже пусто, думаю может отказаться от передачи id через $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection('property-purchase-sale-grid', только не знаю в пользу чего

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/61349-how-to-log-error-500-situations-in-1116/ В теме обсуждается вариант как логировать ошибку, попробуй так же.

Comment: нет, YiiDebug установлен, добавил errorHandler => array(
    'errorAction' => YII_DEBUG ? null : 'site/error'
)
в config/main.php - ситуация не меняется

Comment: Думаю, может стоит попробовать как-нибудь сделать через activeRecord и setAttributes?

Comment: А что в /runtime/application.log ?

Answer (score 1):

А что пишет в /runtime/application.log ?

В Yii есть ActiveRecord, зачем SQL-запросами это всё делать?

```
<?php
...
$count = Properties::model()->count();
...
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('id', $_POST['ids']);
...
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Properties', array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,
    ...
));
```

P.S. Класс Properties уже должен быть, если нет - сгенерируйте с помощью gii

Comment: Это же yii1)) Проверили хоть сами?)

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade я вкурсе. Что именно надо было проверить?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте то что вы уже сказали - конвертируйте $idx в массив, аналогично работающему статичному через

```
$idx = array_map("intval", $_POST['ids']);
```

И в implode можно сделать как

```
implode(',', $idx);
```

без пробелов и др. - там всё сделается автоматически; ну и поменять

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM property WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $idx).")";
```